# cakephp 1.3 belongsto ambiguity 1052 issue

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I am in the midst of migrating a large codebase from cake1.2 to the latest cake1.3 - all has been proceeding nicely until I hit an issue with one of the models and how 
find('all) is generating the SQL request.

The find('all') request is in the comments class controller and requests 3 comment records in their entirety. Each comment SQL record has an angler_id and an author_id foreign and the below stub is from the comments model.

```
class Comment extends AppModel {
 var $name = 'Comment';
 var $belongsTo = array(
 Angler' => array( 'className' => 'Angler' ),
 Author' => array( 'className' => 'Angler' ),
 );
}
```

The angler records have a field called 'favorite lure' among numerous other fields. Author and Angler both refer to angler records. The comment SQL records have an author_id and an angler_id field. This worked perfectly fine in the 1.2 code, but for some reason 1.3 is generating the following SQL request in which the 'favorite lure' field (only that one) is ambiguous and I get a 1052 error code. Note none of the other angler fields are complained about as ambiguous.

Query: SELECT `Comment`.`id`, `Comment`.`catch_id`, `Comment`.`angler_id`, `Comment`.`text`, `Comment`.`datetime`, `Comment`.`author_id`, `Comment`.`private`, `Angler`.`id`, `Angler`.`username`, `Angler`.`password`, `Angler`.`email`, `Angler`.`active`, `Angler`.`autologin_key`, `Angler`.`role`, `Angler`.`first_name`, `Angler`.`last_name`, `Angler`.`address`, `Angler`.`city`, `Angler`.`state`, `Angler`.`zip`, `Angler`.`phone`, `Angler`.`boat`, `favorite lure`, `Angler`.`created`, `Angler`.`ip`, `Angler`.`aoty_rank`, `Angler`.`aoty_points`, `Angler`.`aoty_events`, `Author`.`id`, `Author`.`username`, `Author`.`password`, `Author`.`email`, `Author`.`active`, `Author`.`autologin_key`, `Author`.`role`, `Author`.`first_name`, `Author`.`last_name`, `Author`.`address`, `Author`.`city`, `Author`.`state`, `Author`.`zip`, `Author`.`phone`, `Author`.`boat`, `Author`.`created`, `Author`.`ip`, `Author`.`aoty_rank`, `Author`.`aoty_points`, `Author`.`aoty_events` FROM `comments` AS `Comment` LEFT JOIN `anglers` AS `Angler` ON (`Comment`.`angler_id` = `Angler`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `anglers` AS `Author` ON (`Comment`.`author_id` = `Author`.`id`)  WHERE `Comment`.`private` = 0   ORDER BY `Comment`.`datetime` DESC  LIMIT 3

Both Author and Angler have all the same fields but for some reason things go awry with the 'favorite lure' field. Any advice on solving this is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code that performs the find and the old code which worked fine.

```
// OLD CODE FINDALL
// $comments = $this->Comment->findAll(array('Comment.private' => 0), null, 'Comment.datetime DESC', $count); 
        // 1.3 MOD
        $params = array(
        'conditions' => array('Comment.private' => 0),  //  array
        'fields' => null,           //  array
        'order' => 'Comment.datetime DESC',             //  array or string
        'limit' => $count,      //  int
    //  'page' => ,             // int
    //  'recursive' => 0        // int
        );  

$comments = $this->Comment->find('all', $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so I figured it out. Apparently having a DB field with a space between the words like "favorite lure" is verboten - it worked fine in cakePHP 1.2 but 1.3 has issues with it. Changing it to "favorite_lure" fixed everything.

It even said so at http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Basic-Principles-of-CakePHP/CakePHP-Conventions.html - "Field names with two or more words are underscored like, first_name."

Of course there is no error or warning whatsoever from CakePHP that the field's naming convention is the issue - GRRRRRRR.